# pagination not working on wordpress custom post type

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

This is the code i did for listing custom post type post in wordpress but it doesn't worked pagination what the mistake i did here can any one help ??

```
<div id="talent-main">
   <?php      
   global $wp_query; 
   $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
   $loop = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'talent','posts_per_page' => 2,'paged'=>$paged)); 
   ?>

    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
          <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('multiple') ?>>
              <div class="post-image-talent">
                  <a class="post-frame <?php the_ID(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"></a>
                  <?php the_post_thumbnail('video-talent-thumb'); ?>
              </div>
              <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_short_title('', '...', true, '22') ?></a></h2>
          </div> 
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <div class="navigation">   
        <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>   
        <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>   
    </div>  
</div> <!-- main -->
```

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error? Often times a 404 error with pagination is a result of your post type sharing the same name of a post or page. So if you have a page /calendar and a post type named 'calendar' it would throw a 404 when trying to paginate because WordPress isn't able to determine which to display.

Comment: no it dispaly first 2 post no pagination works @lan

Comment: How many posts do you have? I assume more than 2? If you only have two then that's all it will show...Also, are there other queries being executed on this page? If so you may need to add wp_reset_query just after the endwhile; to get things working again http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check below code?

```
<?php
global $wp_query;  
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'talent',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged,
)); ?>

<?php if($loop->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
          <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('multiple') ?>>
              <div class="post-image-talent">
                  <a class="post-frame <?php the_ID(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"></a>
                  <?php the_post_thumbnail('video-talent-thumb'); ?>
              </div>
              <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_short_title('', '...', true, '22') ?></a></h2>
          </div> 
    <?php endwhile;?>          
    <?php 
    $total_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){

        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
        ));
    }
    ?>    
<?php else :?>
<h3><?php _e('404 Error&#58; Not Found', 'No post found'); ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```